# Active records select value from another model and use for where in current model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have models:

- ProjectAssignment(fields: user_id, project_id)
- User
- Account(relationship has-many projects)
- Membership(fields admin(boolean), role, user_id, account_id)
- Project(has field account_id)

Need find all ProjectAssignments where membership.admin is true.

Need delete all ProjectAssignments where membership.admin is true.

I would like to use active records to do it.
My solution is:

```
Membership.where(admin: true).each do |membership| 
      ids = membership.account.projects.pluck(:id)

      ProjectAssignment.where(id: ids).in_batches do |batch|
        increment_changed_count by: batch.delete_all
      end
    end
```

I don't like my solution. Loop and inside calling another query Activerecords. How can I improve my code?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProjectAssignment.joins(project: { accounts: :memberships }).where('memberships.admin IS TRUE').destroy_all
```

The SQL query may be possible to change depends on your database server.

What I do is join all the tables and make condition with active_record,
you can use raw SQL if you prefer.

Comment: ProjectAssignment doesn't have relationships accounts and memberships.

Comment: Hello~ @Dmitrij I have edited my answer. :)